# When merging in svn can I decide every change?

Tags: svn, merge

I have a project that has a feature branch and a main trunk. I now realise I should have been integrating changes from the trunk into feature branch. When I do this now I get a bit of a mess of source where svn loses important changes on both sides. So.... can I do the merge manually -- where I decide what every change should be?

Comment: What's the hierarchy here? Your use of the word "branch" on both directories makes it kind of hard to follow how your development flow is set up. So is `feature branch` the trunk and `main branch` a branch of `feature branch`? Or are `feature` and `main` both branches off of a singular trunk?

Comment: @Chris sorry, my bad description. I have a trunk. 'feature' was branched from trunk. Both the trunk and feature have evolved. I want to integrate changes from trunk into feature (before commiting feature into trunk). So main = trunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I understand now, thanks for the clarification.

I think we've all been in this situation before and I know it can definitely be hefty to get everything back up in sync. You really have one of two options. The first one, which I recommend, would be to take your feature branch and run `svn merge` in pieces so let's say `feature` was branched on `main` at revision 100 and now we're at revision 150. I would start with

`svn merge -r 101:110` and resolve everything, and commit. Then merge `111-120` (or how many revisions you think you can handle. 10-20 is usually a good number because the amount of commits to `main` would usually only amount to about half of that).

And option #2 (which I've done once before and wasn't nearly as painful as I thought) is if you're really familiar with this feature branch, it's sometimes not a bad idea to re-branch from the trunk, and then start "replaying" your feature branch commits on top of this new branch.

If the difference between the two branches are really great, unfortunately it will take some time.

Comment: Thank you for this. The doing it in bits did it for me. What seemed to confuse svn was I had renamed a couple of files. Getting it over the couple of revisions with the rename help the rest of the merge.

Comment: Yeah the tree conflicts (usually the result of `svn move` or `svn rename`-ing files) can be quite tedious at times if there are a lot of them or if there is a lot of code in said file(s). There have been a number of times where dev branches with my teammates have gotten completely out of sync with each other, so this is the method I always tell my team to do whenever they get stuck. Cheers!